# Threads copied from child process to parent

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pyserial

I have a serial logging utility that process logs from COM port and sends them to DB. I'm using pyserial ReaderThread with conjunction with protocol factory.

```
class SerialLogging(Process):
    def __init__(self, cpath, q):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.__queue = q
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.optionxform = str 
        config.read(cpath)
        self.__configs = list()
        for section in config.sections():
            self.__configs.append(dict(config.items(section)))
        if len(self.__configs) <= 0:
            return 1

        self.__serials = list()
        for config in self.__configs:
           if config['status'] == 'on':
              self.__serials.append({'thread': threaded.ReaderThread(serial.Serial(config['port'], baudrate=config['baudrate'], timeout=1),  lambda config=config: PrintLines(config['device'])), 'port': config['port'], 'device': config['device'], 'baudrate' : config['baudrate']})

        for ser in self.__serials:
            try:
                ser['thread'].start()
                ser['status'] = 'on'
            except:
                ser['status'] = 'off'


    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.__queue.get_nowait()
                self.__queue.task_done()
            except queue.Empty:
                continue
            if 'close' in message:
                self.__disable(message.split(' ')[1])
                self.__queue.put('ok')
            elif 'run' in message:
                self.__enable(message.split(' ')[1])
                self.__queue.put('ok')
            elif 'list' in message:
                self.__queue.put(self.__list())
        return       

    def __disable(self, port):
        for serial in self.__serials:
            if serial['port'] == port and serial['status'] == 'on':
                serial['thread'].close()
                serial['status'] = 'off'    

    def __enable(self, port):
        for ser in self.__serials:
            if ser['port'] == port and ser['status'] == 'off':
                ser['thread'] = threaded.ReaderThread(serial.Serial(ser['port'], baudrate=ser['baudrate'], timeout=1), lambda ser=ser: PrintLines(ser['device']))
                ser['thread'].start()
                ser['status'] = 'on'

    def __list(self):
        return ['%s=%s %s' % (serial['port'], serial['device'], serial['status']) for serial in self.__serials]
```

SerialLogging class is instantiated as a separate process.
The problem is that ReaderThreads are somehow copied from child process(where they're started to parent process), so when I stop the thread, it only stops in child process and continues to log information from parent process.
Any suggestions on this issue? Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I was creating threads in child process, which was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating threads in child process, which was wrong.